# Restricting access property in subclass

Tags: c#, properties, subclass

I have a class with a public property, that I want to restrict access to _for_some_modules_.
(The modules that use this class reside in different assemblies, so internal does not help.)

My first thought was to subclass, and make the derived property accessor private or protected, but this is not possible. The derived property has to have the same access rights. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd.aspx)

Any suggestions? I assume it is a common task to make a more restricted variant of a class?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is possible - once you cross the assembly boundary, all bets are off.

Comment: could I see a skeletal version of your class? Usually, something like this can be resolved by a more intentional design.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) to make the `internal` members of the class visible to other assemblies (as many as you like). The documentation page has an example.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume it is a common task to make a
>   more restricted variant of a class?

This is not a common task since it violates the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) - you can't use the sub class the same way as you would use the base class in regards to the property you restrict access to. You should consider refactoring your class hierarchy.

You could solve the problem through composition - make the class `A` internal only and write a public wrapper class that has a member of type `A` and delegates and controls access to the `A`'s properties / methods.

Answer (score 1):

Making more restricted subclasses is actually not common because it would break consumers of the base class that assumed they had access to the public members. In general, your classes should start out restrictive and get less so as they specialize, not vice-versa.

The concept you're looking for is called a "friend" class in other languages, but C# (purposely) doesn't implement them. The InternalsVisibleToAttribte is as close as it gets, but that is applied at the assembly level, so it may not work for you.

Without more information on why you are trying to restrict access this way, it's hard to give any good general-purpose alternatives. The access modifiers like public/private/etc aren't designed to be a security mechanism, since Reflection will get you access to read/write everything regardless. They're more of a hint to the consumers as to what is safe to use --  public members will usually remain stable across new versions, while private (implementation-detail) members are more likely to change.

Comment: Thanks for the insight (also to BrokenGlass below) about not making subclasses more restrictive.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is making a subset of a Model class. The Model class would be the base class, and the derived class a subset (or a view of the model). The purpose is that different consumers would only see relevant parts of the Model. I would like to avoid copy-paste to get the relevant properties to the subset class. (And I would like to avoid Reflection, because it may be difficult to understand for other developers...)

Answer (score 0):

You can always do something like this:

```
class MyBaseClass
{
    protected string MyRestrictedProperty { get; set; }
}

class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public string MyPublicProperty 
    {
        get { return MyRestrictedProperty;  }
        set { MyRestrictedProperty = value; }
    }
}
```